# check used stack size using core file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, stack-trace

I have a core file where the application terminated with SIGSEGV.
I suspect this is because the application ran out of stack space.
Is there any way to check the used stack size from the core file?

Comment: It somewhat depends on the operating system and architecture. Can you add those to your question?

Comment: OS is Linux, 64 bit x86

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you think your stack size limit has been reached due to infinite recursion, an easy way to determine this is to run `bt` or `info stack` and see if there are many more frames than you expect. Here's an example where I recursively called a function with around 1024 bytes of local data in each stack frame:

```
(gdb) info stack
#0  recurse () at loop.c:5
#1  0x0000000000400565 in recurse () at loop.c:5
...
#7939 0x0000000000400565 in recurse () at loop.c:5
#7940 0x000000000040058f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffe63afef48) at loop.c:10
```

You can also exceed the stack size limit with just a few frames if you have a large amount of local data in the frames.

To check the approximate size of the stack, on Linux/x86 you can check the difference between `_environ`, which contains a high address that's fairly close to the base of the stack, and `$sp`, the stack pointer in the current frame (top of stack).

```
(gdb) print (char *)_environ - (char *)$sp
$5 = 8384904
```

This looks pretty close to the stack size limit of 8MB.

```
(gdb) shell ulimit -s
8192
```

You can also look at the difference between the  $sp in the frame at the top of the stack and the $sp in the frame at the base of the stack.

```
(gdb) frame 0
#0  recurse () at loop.c:5
(gdb) set $topsp=$sp
(gdb) frame 7940
#7940 0x000000000040058f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffe63afef48) at loop.c:10
(gdb) print (char *)$sp - (char *)$topsp
$6 = 8384640
```

Comment: How about  "aarch64 GNU/Linux"?

Answer (score 4):

There is a nifty way to get the stack size in the program.

You can store the address of the first variable in main in a global. Then you can make a function which finds the difference between this address and the current stack address. This will give you the stack size used within 2 bytes.

In main.

```
char * initaddr;
int main()
{
   char dummy;  // Note -- first variable declared.

   initaddr = &dummy;

   // Other stuff...
}

int stacksize(void)
{
   char dummy2, *lastptr;
   lastptr = &dummy2;

   return(lastptr-initaddr); // This will give the stacksize at the instant of the return function.
}
```

You can call this function to determine the stacksize used upto that point. This can be used as a debug tool.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, but to be sure that you run out of stack space , you can use ulimit system  command to determine the stack size : ulimit -a.
After that you can increase  is with ulimit -s and try to see if you are still coring. 
The default value for stack size is quite large , but maybe for the user that runs the program the stack size  was decreased.

Comment: Firstly wellcome to Stack Overflow. It would be really goodidea to add a tags to your question.

Comment: I did find a way using gdb. By checking the difference between the sp register of the starting and ending frame in the backtrace. Seems correct?